# При выполнении теста своего метода, для заполнения Dictionary , он полностью забивает память. Тест не может остановиться

Tags: c#, xunit

Подскажите ошибку в коде. Мне необходимо создать Dictionary и заполнить её странами  с ключом это код страны , например RU, а значение это наименование Россия. Я использую RegionInfo, CultureInfo , просто прохожусь циклом и идет заполнение.  Второй метод , принимает текст и ищет там коды стран , после чего должен вывести их значения. Пробую использовать xUnit (первый раз, нету опыта с ним) , когда запускаю метод , то он просто бесконечно грузит и в итоге переполняет память , что все виснет.

Тест:

```
 public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ItShould_UnderTesting()
        { 
            //Arrange
            var sut = new CountriesFilter();

            //Act
           var d = sut.Text_Regul("gh bbff swvw'RU', 'DE' ggg ");

            //Assert

            Assert.NotNull(d);

        }
```

Код:

```
      public class CountriesFilter
            {
                public static IDictionary<string, string> GettingTextReg()
                {
                    var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
                    
        
        
                    var codeandname = new Dictionary<string, string>(allCultures.Length);
        
                    foreach(var i in allCultures)
                    {
                        RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(i.Name);
                        if (codeandname.Count(x => x.Key == regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName) == 0)
                        {
        
                            codeandname.Add(regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName, regionInfo.DisplayName);
                        }
                    }
        
                    return codeandname;
                }
    
    public List<string> Text_Regul(string text)
            {
    
                List<string> coun = null;
                try
                {
                    var list = GettingTextReg();
    
                    string pattern = string.Format("\'({0})\'", string.Join("|", list.Keys));
    
                    Match mat = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
    
                    coun = new List<string>();
    
                    while (mat.Success)
                    {
                        coun.Add(mat.Value);
                    }
    
                    
    
                } catch(ArgumentNullException e)
                {
    
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(e.Message);
                }
    
               return coun;
          

  }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: [NextMatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Match_NextMatch) забыли

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (mat.Success)
{
    coun.Add(mat.Value);
}
```

— это бесконечный цикл. Вы всё время добавляете одно и то же значение, ничего не меняется между итерациями.

Вероятно, вы хотели написать

```
foreach (Match mat in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
{
    coun.Add(mat.Value);
}
```

Comment: спасибо! не обратил внимание на это ..

Comment: @Daniel Vai: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!